# how to bypass exception to debug EXE

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, anti-debugging, exception

i am trying to debug and find the encryption password algorithm in a Windows Application.
Whenever i try to debug, setting a breakpoint or not, the application gives a exception:

[image: exception message]

is it some kind of anti-debug that creates this exception? if yes, anyway i can  bypass it?

Another information, the application has a login splash screen and when i try to run the debugger this screen shows and then the exception is raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this exception is used to [set the thread name for the debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs). You should be able to safely ignore it.